# Nodejs. Deploy On digitalOcean, ES module Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I just made my first Website, using the MERN stack, Now want to deploy it on the digital ocean, the frontend part is working ok, my Nginx configuration is ok, but I have a problem with backend, my server.js file, is not working, it is causing this error

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:

I am using the import and export ES module, and also have "type": "module" in my package.json,

The app is working ok on a local server,

Can anyone help?

here is my server.js file

```
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import colors from 'colors'
import {
  notFound,
  errorHandler
} from './middleware/errorMiddlleware.js'
import connectDB from './config/db.js'
import eventRouter from './routes/eventsRoute.js'
import blogRouter from './routes/blogRoute.js'
import userRouter from './routes/userRoutes.js'
import uploadRouter from './routes/uploadRoutes.js'

dotenv.config()
connectDB()
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api/events', eventRouter)
app.use('/api/blogs', blogRouter)
app.use('/api/users', userRouter)
app.use('/api/uploads', uploadRouter)

const dirname = path.resolve()
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(dirname, '/uploads')))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')))

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('App Is Running...')
  })
}

app.use(notFound)
app.use(errorHandler)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(Server Is Running In $ {
      process.env.NODE_ENV
    }
    Mode On Port $ {
      PORT
    }.yellow.bold)
})
```

Comment: Your `console.log` at the end is missing the tick marks at the beginning and end of the string...

Comment: No, I don't know why it converted like this, but  in my editor I have tick marks, it is not causing error :)

Comment: What version of node are you running on DO vs your local?

Comment: I would suggest [edit]ing your question to fix the code to prevent closure...

Comment: @proxim0  DO have 12.22.1  and local 14.14.0

Comment: You may want to try your code locally on 12.22.1 because you could be using something that is new to node > 12.22.1

Comment: I Just rewrite my code and use commonjs, require, and module. exports, and it is working, thanks